# How to use React.js to render server-side template on Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sails.js

I am trying to build an isomorphing app with Sails.js and React. Client-side part is easy. But I run into problems with server-side rendering.

When I try to server-render an *.jsx file with React, I got this:

```
renderToString(): You must pass a valid ReactElement
```

I am using sailsjs, react and sails-hook-babel (for ES6 syntax).

./assets/components/Auth.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='auth'>
        Very simple element without any logic just for test server-rendering.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

./api/controllers/AuthController.js:

```
var Auth = require('./../../assets/components/Auth.jsx');
import React from 'react';

module.exports = {
    render: function (req, res) {
    //var markup = React.renderToString(
    //  Auth
    //); // This throws an error

    console.log(Auth); // {__esModule: true, Auth: [Function: Auth]}

    //res.view("layout", {app: markup});
  }
};
```

I have tried both ES5/ES6 syntax everywhere. Error occurs everytime. At clientside this Auth.jsx works fine (I am using webpack with babel-loader).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem isn't with your component itself, it's how you're exporting it from your module.

When using just `export` you need to import your module like this.

```
import {Auth} from 'auth';
```

Just using `export` allows for exporting more than 1 thing from your module.

```
// My Module.
export function a(x) {
    console.log('a');
}

export function b(x, y) {
    console.log('b');
}

import { a, b } from 'myModule';
```

or you can use `import * from 'myModule';`
This is called a *named export*.

What your use case begs for is the use of `export default` which allows a single object to be exported from your module.

```
export default class Auth extends React.Component {}
```

Thus letting you import your module as a single object without curly braces.

```
import Auth from 'auth';
```

Then you need to render using either use JSX syntax `React.renderToString(<Auth />);` or
`React.createElement(Auth);`

You can read all on how modules in ECMA Script 6 works [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Comment: Shame on me, but I don't get it :( tried `var markup = React.renderToString(
     React.createElement(Auth)
    );` didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! For answer and link, it's very useful.