# How to use an ejs variable inside a react render function?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, ejs

I'm passing a variable `abcd` to my index.ejs which in turn calls a react js file to render the index.ejs page. I've been able to access `<%= abcd %>` inside index.ejs but not inside the render function of react. Can you help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem but with a index.html file, filled by a React component, and resolved it like this:

**In index.html**

```
<script>
    window.abcd = '<%- abcd %>';
</script>
```

**In your react component**

```
render: function(){
    return(
       <div>
            <p> {window.abcd} </p>
       </div>
    );
}
```

This worked perfectly for me, if someone has a cleaner proposition, i'm in!

Comment: run into similar problem. I see other render the React component on the server side. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412590/how-to-use-react-js-to-render-server-side-template-on-sails-js

Comment: You saved my next day.., was looking this answer from last few hours, and just found before signing off for the day..