# How to use an ejs variable inside a react render function with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ejs

I want my users to see some personalized info they have stored in a MySQL database.

I use ejs/webpack/React. I also found the following answer but it doesn't account for using webpack: [How to use an ejs variable inside a react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266810/how-to-use-an-ejs-variable-inside-a-react-render-function)

So, I thought inside router.get to pass the info as variable(s):

```
router.get('/profile', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', { title: 'Profile', abcd: 'MySQL info') });
});
```

then in profile.ejs:

```
<script src='bundle.js'>
    window.abcd = '<%- abcd %>';
</script>
```

and in the react component

```
render: function(){
    return(
       <div>
            <p> {window.abcd} </p>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Since I'm using webpack, my .js files cannot see the `window.abcd` variable.

I don't want to use POST method and I don't want to use an external .js file with my variable. Is there any clean option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `window.abcd = '<%- abcd %>'` above the `script` tag. When the `bundle.js` is executed, `window.abcd` will be available.

**Example**

```
<script>window.abcd = '<%- abcd %>'</script>
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
```

Hope this helps!