# SSR for react-redux application with sails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js, server-side-rendering

I am creating a nodejs project with `sails` framework , and want to use react SSR (server side rendering) with sails (not `express` or another thing).

I ask some questions of my self when want to use sails SSR :

- Could we use `sails` for SSR ? (as it has no documentation to do
  that)
- Could we trust some libraries like : [sails-hook-next](https://github.com/RasCarlito/sails-hook-next) for
  production usage of sails SSR ?
- What about using `express` and having two servers running . [[express-react-redux-server-side-rendering]](https://medium.com/@dai_shi/express-react-redux-server-side-rendering-with-router-v4-and-webpack-v2-plus-hmr-43418b85a0d4)

Comment: I plan to do this soon, I studied sails and I'm very sure it's possible. I will share a solution once I implement.

Comment: @Noitidart thank you , if you can notice me about news :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412590/how-to-use-react-js-to-render-server-side-template-on-sails-js

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what is the purpose of your application, can't say much.

But if you wanna do **SSR** with **React** I recommend you to have a look this framework https://github.com/zeit/next.js, use it as your front-end and sails as a API.

nextjs has rich documents and plenty of example, you can use it without touching server or with you own custom server like Express, Hapi, Koa.